# neo4j best practices to store and stream video and images?

Tags: image, audio, video, neo4j, streaming

I started learning about neo4j recently, and have read a lot of articles, however I'm kind of lost on what is the best practices to store and stream video's picture's audio on neo 4j... I know about BLOB but I've heard it is not good to store it there, so can someone recomand a tool or cloud service I could use for storing these, keep in mind I would store and stream as well as delete a lot of videos, image and audios daily on the same time, or if neo4j has a recommend solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience with Neo4j I do not think you want to store blobs or base64 encoded data inside of the database. Depending on what you want to achieve I would probably recommend storing a path or url to where the video, audio and pictures can be found inside of Neo4j.

Comment: I would be using a mobile app to access these videos and pictures, so is it better to store them on another server that neo4j can connect to? I do not want the app has any direct access to the video url or location for security reasons. Or should they be stored on another database all together that is capable of handling these video/picture requests? I'm new on this topic :(

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like you should have something more in your environment than a mobile app connecting directly to Neo4j. I see Neo4j as a database, so you should put another layer with buissnes logic between Neo and your app.